# Algorithm to find and fix Date Intersects

Tags: c#, algorithm, date

I have a an object that includes a date range

```
public class MyObject
{
     public int Id {get; set;}         

     public string Name {get; set;}

     public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}

     public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to pass in an instance of MyObject and check to make sure all other objects that have intersecting dates, such as

```
var myObj = new MyObject
    {
         Id = 1,
         Name = "Test",
         StartDate = new Date(2017, 3,1),
         EndDate = new Date(2017, 3,10)
    };

foreach(var objInList in objList)
  {
          bool done = false;
            //if both dates are inside rnage
            if (objInList.StartDate <= myObj.StartDate && myObj.StartDate <= objInList.EndDate
                && objInList.StartDate<= myObj.EndDate && myObj.EndDate<= objInList.EndDate)
            {// update start and end

                done = true;
            }
            // if start of new item is in range, but end isnt
            else if (objInList.StartDate<= myObj.StartDate && myObj.StartDate <= objInList.EndDate)
            {
                if (!done)
                {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            // if both dates are inside range
            else if (objInList.StartDate<= myObj.EndDate && myObj.EndDate <= objInList.EndDate)
            {
                if (!done)
                { }
            }
  }
```

Basically I need to update objInList to ensure that there are no date intersects after the loop. I am having a hard time putting the logic in place without it getting overly complicated.

Comment: What is the `Date` type here? Is this your own type? It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] with properly indented code and sample input/expected output - I'm finding it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Sorry it is .Net DateTime. I updated the example. I am looking to check if the date of myObj intersects any date range in objList. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well sort of, but it's not "the date" so much as "the date range". I would suggest the first thing you may want to do is create a `DateRange` type where you can put most of the logic. (It doesn't help that the badly-formatted code you've shown only sets `done` - it's not doing anything else.) Again, a [mcve] would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

The code for checking date range intersects is as follows:

```
MyObject a = ...
MyObject b = ...
DateTime maxStart = a.StartDate > b.StartDate ? a.StartDate : b.StartDate;
DateTime minEnd = a.EndDate < b.EndDate ? a.EndDate : b.EndDate;
bool intersect = (maxStart < minEnd);
```

Comment: Sorry it is a DateTime. I am more concerned about updating the dates of the obj that the intersection occurs. Does that make sense

Comment: @IsaacLevin Removing an intersection is absolutely up to you. Come up with a strategy what you do after detecting an overlap. The number of possibilities is endless, so you need to pick one strategy. You need to decide what to do when intervals simply intersect (pull in the end/pull forward the start, pick a middle, etc) vs what to do when one interval contains the other in its entirety (drop one of two objects? Create two additional objects to represent the cut?)

Answer (score 0):

I hope i helps you:

```
private bool IsTimeBetween(DateTime theTime, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        if (theTime >= startTime && theTime <= endTime)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void check()
    {
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Test",
            StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 3, 1),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 3, 10)
        };

        List<MyObject> objList = new List<MyObject>();

        foreach (var objInList in objList)
        {
            if (objInList.StartDate >= objInList.EndDate)
                continue;

            if (IsTimeBetween(objInList.StartDate, myObj.StartDate, myObj.EndDate)
                || IsTimeBetween(objInList.EndDate, myObj.StartDate, myObj.EndDate))
            {
                //intersects
            }

            if (objInList.StartDate < myObj.StartDate && objInList.EndDate > myObj.EndDate)
            {
                //intersects
            }
        }
    }
```